# How to play sound and view pictures with Fancybox and the same time?

Tags: fancybox, mp3, image

My goal is to allow someone to view several images and play, pause,
stop an audio file that will play when someone views the images.

Deliverable: multiple images that scroll to the next picture using
fancybox navigation and an audio player at the bottom that plays a
single audio clip.

I think I probably need to add a div at the bottom of Fancybox and
then embed my player. What's the proper method? I'm a bit new with JQuery and
Fancybox :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these API options instead of `onComplete` and `onClosed`

```
'titlePosition' : 'inside',
'titleFormat'   : function(title) {
 return '<span>'+title+'<br /><embed style="position:absolute;" src="test_song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" controller="false" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" width="1" height="1" /></span>';
}
```

of course, check that the `embed` part is correct (I just copy/paste from your code) ... you may test it as a normal html `embed` in your page.

**NOTE**: this is for fancybox v1.3.x